# Prove that $\lambda(v-1) = r(k-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

This is to do with balanced incomplete block design. Some homework exercise wants me to prove the relation 
$$\lambda(v-1) = r(k-1)$$

$v$ is the number of elements in your ground set.

$r$ is the number of blocks containing a given element

$k$ is the number of elements in each block.

$\lambda$ is the number of blocks containing each pair of elements.

I don't really know where to begin with this, especially since this is the only equation that I have ever used $\lambda$ for.

Comment: What are $r$, $\lambda$, $k$ and $v$?

Comment: I've added a "design-of-experiments" tag. That's where the problem came from. I think it began in agricultural field trials in about 1930 or so, with the work of Ronald Fisher. Fisher's Ph.D. was in mathematics and he is on a very short list of the most famous scientists of the 20th century, as one of the three major founders (with Haldane and Wright) of population genetics, and as the most illustrious ever of theorists of statistics, but it seems many mathematicians have not heard of him. I've nominated the question for re-opening. I think it's crystal-clear about what the four variables are.

Comment: I agree with Michael Hardy in that the question is crystal clear in the given context of BIBDs, so I cast a vote to reopen. It is basic and standard, so I would expect all textbooks on combinatorial designs to have this. Possibly we can criticize the OP for not showing effort, but if he has not seen this kind of double counting argument ever before, then he has very little to work with.

Answer (score 5):

I assume here (although you should really specify) the following meanings for the parameters:

- $v$ is the number of elements in your ground set.
- $r$ is the number of blocks containing a given element
- $k$ is the number of elements in each block.
- $\lambda$ is the number of blocks containing each pair of elements.

Assuming that this is correct: notice that if $x$ is a fixed element of your ground set, then $\lambda(v-1)$ is the number of ways of choosing a pair $(y,B)$, where $y\neq x$ and $B$ is a block such that $x,y\in B$.

Can you prove that the number of such pairs is also $r(k-1)$?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on a two design, if that is so. Then you can use the gen eqn: $(v-i)\lambda_{i+1} = (k-i)\lambda_i$, $i$ is between $0$ and $t-1$. (Boggs and White p.57)
There you'll have $i=1$, $(v-1)\lambda_2 = (k-1)\lambda_1$, and we know that $\lambda_2 = \lambda_t = \lambda$ and $\lambda_1 = r$. Thus you have your equation :)

Comment: you might want to make your answer more readable

Comment: @ChristianAlvinBuhat: It really helps to format answers using MathJax.